# Can the limit of the MSE of an estimator be infinity?

Tags: statistics, estimation

Is it ever possible for the limit of the MSE of an estimator be infinity?

I was doing an exercise and it turns out that the estimator is consistent but the limit of the MSE is infinity, so I am wondering if this result makes sense or did I make a mistake somewhere. I do know that just because the estimator is consistent, that does not mean that the limit of its MSE must be 0. But I did not expect that the limit of an MSE can ever be infinity. If this is true, then what is the interpretation of this kind of estimator?

Comment: What is "MSE" ?

Comment: Mean Squared Error.

Comment: Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: A limit with respect to what?

Comment: With respect to the sample size.

Comment: This question could use more formulation.  Anyway, for example, if you are estimating a parameter $\theta$ with samples $X_i = \theta + N_i$ where $N_i$ are mutually independent zero mean and infinite variance for all $i \in \{1, 2, 3,\ldots\}$, then any estimator $\hat{X}_K = \frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^K X_i$ will have infinite variance (infinite MSE) for all $K$, and hence also in the limit.  Alternatively, if the noise has finite variance but we use a _bad_ estimator, like one that does not depend on the samples (say, $\hat{X}_K = K$), then we can easily have $MSE\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: In general, if your estimator gets worse and worse as the number of samples gets larger, the interpretation is that this is a "bad estimator."

Comment: @Michael: If $N_i$ have infinite variance, will the mean $\hat X_K$ still be able to be a consistent estimator of $\theta$, i.e. converge with probability $1$? I'm not sure, but there will at least be some additional restrictions on the distribution of $N$.

Comment: @EinarRødland , If the estimator is $\hat{X}_K = \frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^K(\theta + N_i) = \theta + \frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^KN_i$, then this converges (with prob 1) to $\theta$ as $K\rightarrow\infty$. This is by the Law of Large Numbers for i.i.d. random variables $\{N_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ with mean 0 (even if the variance is infinite).

Comment: @Michael: I guess you're right. I though for a while I could force the running average of the $N_i$ to get infinitely many jumps of size $\epsilon>0$, but now realise that finite $\text{E}[|N|]$ prevents that.